# MacOS app built with py2app won't render dot graph into pdf file

Tags: python-3.x, macos, graphviz, dot, py2app

I have built a standalone macOS app using py2app from a single .py script. The app is supposed to generate and render some graph using graphviz framework.

Running the MyApp.app by double-clicking works fine until it has to render and preview the resulting graph (in pdf), then nothing happens. I found that the .gv source file is created, but the rendered .pdf is never created nor shown.

Interestingly, running the .py script manually through terminal worked fine, same thing with running it through PyCharm and even running /MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp from terminal.

Relevant code:

```
G = Digraph(path)
# add some nodes and edges here
G.render(view=True)
```

So far I have tried changing output formats for rendering and changing the path for generated .gv file, but with no success. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I'm using Python v3.7.0, graphviz v2.40.1 and py2app v0.15